# Why does usedJSHeapSize always increase when we open Chrome with “--enable-precise-memory-info” even though I didn't do anything in the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am experimenting with closures and garbage collection in javascript. Having the information about memory is really handy. I am trying to make use of `window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize` but I have no idea:

1. Why the output keeps increasing even though I am not doing anything in the page?
2. <s>Why when I refresh page several times the initial output is slightly different? *3xxxxxx -> refresh -> 4xxxxxx -> refresh -> 6xxxxxx -> 3xxxxxx* - do you see the pattern? Does that mean, that garbage collector is triggered  - let's  say - once per 3 refreshes?</s> My suspicions were confirmed by adding `gc()` on load.

If you want to play around with my simple educational tool the code is [at my github](https://github.com/3amprogrammer/gc-and-closures/tree/master).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the output keeps increasing even though I am not doing anything in the page?

If you compare heap snapshots using the "Heap Snapshots" or capture the "Allocation timelines" from the "Profiles" webdev tab, you would see that during `setTimeout` callback call only an in object of the `MemoryInfo` is allocated.

And then it becomes immediately obvious - that the `var memory = window.performance.memory;` statement triggers a getter that returns you a new object every time, that must be allocated. After the callback returns it's a candidate for collection.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir. Indeed that was my problem. Now I do `memory = null; gc()` and everything works fine.